# Powershell Export-csv exporting only header

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv, export-csv

I have a comma delimited text file that I am trying to run through a script to only grab the data from the current month. When I run the script it outputs a file that only contains the header row and the rest are just lines of commas:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3, Jan
,,,
,,,
,,,
```

The original files columns consists of the named headers and then 12 months of data where the headers are the 3 letter abbreviation of the month. ie: January = Jan

My code is here:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format MMM

(Import-CSV "C:\file.txt") |
    Select "Header1","Header2","Header3","$date" |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter "," -path "C:\temp.txt" -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

Also, if I do not have the first pipe, the powershell window correctly displays the data I am trying to get but puts out an empty file.

Comment: What you want to use to filter things is a `Where{}` statement, not a `Select` statement. Something like `Import-CSV C:\file.txt | Where{(Get-Date $_.Date).Month -eq (get-date).Month}|Export-Csv c:\temp.txt -del ',' -notype` (that is assuming you have a column labled 'Date' in your original file)

Comment: No, the file consists of 12 columns of monetary data where the header is the 3 letter abbreviation of the month. I have updated the question with this info, but I will try adjusting your solution to work.

Comment: Please provide a sample CSV. Also, please try to reduce your code sample to the required minimum to reprocude the issue. (Let's say you `Import-CSV` is not successful, then everything else is irelevant for the question.)

Comment: You are using `Import-Csv` on a .txt file which doesn't make much sense, is this actually a CSV? You're also piping `foreach-object` to remove the `"` to `Export-Csv` when this cmdlet doesn't produce any output. There aren't enough details on the question to provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I remedied this myself by assigning the imported data to a variable.

```html
$date = Get-Date -Format MMM

$data = (Import-CSV "C:\file.txt") |
    Select "Header1","Header2","Header3","$date" |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter "," -path "C:\temp.txt" -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```